# Ruby Fails to load a DLL

Tags: c, ruby

I'm using Ruby 1.8.6 on Windows. I'm extending Ruby with C, that is I want to load a DLL into Ruby. But Ruby fails load my Dll. I use Visual Studio.net command prompt and integrate my DLL, namely prov.dll, into a C program, pro1.c. After that, I call those C functions through Ruby.

```
D:\ruby_extend\pronmake>irb
irb(main):001:0> require 'pro1'
=> true
irb(main):002:0> include Pro
=> Object
irb(main):003:0> Pro::load
=> false
irb(main):004:0>
```

I only get an error:

```
DLL fails to load through ruby...
```

How can I get the stacktrace? Any advice would help me out.

Below is my pro1.c code:

```
#include "windows.h"
#include "ruby.h"
#include "pro.h"
#define _D(string) {OutputDebugString(string);}
VALUE Pro;
HINSTANCE hlibrary;

void _textline(const char *s, int len)
//************************************
{
    _D(s);
}

static VALUE p_load(VALUE self )
//******************************
{
       return pro_load();
}

static VALUE p_init(VALUE self)
//*****************************
{
    _D("-> init");
         pro_set_textline_callback(_textline);
    pro_renderInit();
}

static VALUE p_parse(VALUE self, VALUE string_to_parse)
//*****************************************************
{
    _D(StringValuePtr(string_to_parse));
    return pro_parse(StringValuePtr(string_to_parse));
}

void proeventcallback(proRenderEventType type, proRenderEventData data)
//************************************************************************
{
    switch(type){
        case proRenderEventDone:
            _D("-> cleanup");
            pro_renderCleanUp();
            //if (vWindow)
            //{
            //  SendMessage((HWND)NUM2INT(vWindow), WM_USER+2, 0, 0);
            //}
    }
}

static VALUE pro_render( VALUE self )
//**********************************
{
    _D("-> render");
    pro_set_renderevent_callback(proeventcallback);
    SetThreadPriority(GetCurrentThread(),THREAD_PRIORITY_ABOVE_NORMAL);
    pro_render(PRO_RENDERASYNC);
    return Qtrue;
}

void Init_pro1()
//***************
{
    pro = rb_define_module( "Pro" );
    rb_define_method(Pro, "load", p_load, 0);
    rb_define_method( Pro, "init_engine", p_init, 0 );
    rb_define_method(Pro, "parse", p_parse, 1);
    rb_define_method(Pro, "render", pr_render, 0);   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would look at the definition of `pro_load()`, since that seems to be what's determining the return value of `Pro::load` in your ruby code.